How to get total records in SwiftData so can display the proper records or ContentUnavailableView (Custom or .search)
Watched Paul Hudson long SwiftData Tutorial and wanted to modify it by putting in the built-in ContentUnavailableView.search “No Search Results” view and also a custom “ContentUnavailableView” when there are no physical records/objects in SwiftData Person class to start. This custom View has an "add" button.
Got it working by using a computed property private var allPeople: Int that gives me the count and then if-else to make the decision.  Is there another or better way of grabbing this "Person" count and is this the proper way to branch based on this count using .onAppear?  I have seen .overlay used but wasn't sure which was the proper design method.
Whatever I use to keep track of the count in ContentView, I need to send into PeopleView so I can update the count if I delete someone in there.
Still learning and thanks,
Scott
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    @State private var destPath = NavigationPath()
    @State private var sortOrder = [SortDescriptor(\Person.name)]
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    // Current "Person" count
    @State private var personCount = 0
    
    // TEST - Finding the total object count for Person and see if I could keep it updated in this view
    private var allPeople: Int {
        let decriptor = FetchDescriptor<Person>(predicate: #Predicate { !$0.name.isEmpty })
        return (try? modelContext.fetchCount(decriptor)) ?? 0
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $destPath) {
            Group {
                if personCount > 0 {
                    PeopleView(searchString: searchText, weHavePeople: $personCount, sortOrder: sortOrder)
                        .navigationTitle("Face Facts Man: \(personCount)")
                        .toolbar {
                            Menu("Sort", systemImage: "arrow.up.arrow.down") {
                                Picker("Sort", selection: $sortOrder) {
                                    "
                                    "
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Button("Add Person", systemImage: "plus", action: addPerson)
                        }
                        .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Find Some People...")   
                } else {
                    ContentUnavailableView(label: {
                        Label("You Must Know Someone", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                    }, description: {
                        Text("ContentView: Go ahead, add some people! \(personCount)")
                    }, actions: {
                        Button("Add A Person", systemImage: "person.badge.plus", action: addPerson)
                            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Person.self) { chosenPerson in
                EditPersonView(person: chosenPerson, navPath: $destPath)
            }
            // TEST: Put in to see if the count was updating and assign so that we can branch above in Group
            .onAppear {
                personCount = allPeople
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*
     Creates the new person and inserts it as "blank" into context.  Then change the destPath
     to the correct Person we are going to edit.  It's now binded and auto-saving is now done as
     fields are changed on edit screen.
    */
    func addPerson() {
        let newPerson = Person(name: "", emailAddress: "", details: "")
        modelContext.insert(newPerson)
        destPath.append(newPerson)
    }
}


Not exactly sure what you mean but why not move the fetchCount related code into a function and then call that function whenever you need to update your count property.

Joakim - Sorry for not being completely clear.  Was curious if SwiftData had a better way to get the count.  And if using .onAppear was the proper way to update that count early enough so that my if-else would branch to show the rows PeopleView returns or puts up my custom ContentUnavailableView view.  The only reason I am passing the count into PeopleView is so I can update it if I delete someone.
